# checkbox being checked on false - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
$('#checkyes').prop('checked', row['checkb']);
var check = row['checkb'];
alert(check);
$('#checkyes').checkboxradio('refresh');
```

The alert correctly shows the value inside row['checkb'] to be false, yet the checkbox gets ticked anyway.  Am I missing some quotations somewhere or can I not use the row value?

Comment: Is `row['checkb']` value string/boolean?

Comment: Ah of course...it's probably a string, thanks I'll change it now to see if it works

Comment: Problem is SQLite doesn't have a true/false value it has 0 or 1 which are stored as integers apparently, how would I get round this using prop()?

Comment: Use an assessment, maybe? `row['checkb'] === 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#checkyes').prop('checked', (row['checkb'] == 'true') ? true : false);
```

Or

```
$('#checkyes').prop('checked', (row['checkb'] == 'true') );
```

---

Or

```
var chk = (row['checkb'] == 'true') ? true : false; //Or var chk = (row['checkb'] == 'true');
$('#checkyes').prop('checked', chk );
```

---

**Problem**

`row['checkb']` has value string `true` or `false` not Boolean value .

So `$('#checkyes').prop('checked', row['checkb']);` will evaluate to checked.

String value here `prop('checked', String)` makes it true for all cases .

Answer (score 0):

```
 var isResult = (row['checkb'] == 0) ? false : true; 
 $('#checkyes').prop('checked', isResult);

  $('#checkyes').prop('checked', JSON.parse(row['checkb']));
```

Comment: The assessment will return a Boolean; you don't need to see if it's true/false and then return true/false.

Comment: Problem is SQLite doesn't have a true/false value it has 0 or 1 told by question owner

Comment: that why i check with zero

Comment: Wonderful, so why not assess for the conditions it has (integers 0 and 1, according to comments to the question itself) to represent false/true? Either way the assessment results in a Boolean, so why not use that?

Comment: Thanks, I undersood @DavidThomas

Answer (score 0):

From [Tushar Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224265/tushar-gupta)'s answer, I'd suggest:

```
$('#checkyes').prop('checked', row['checkb'] == 'true');
```

Comment: In this cas you simply use JSON.parse(row['checkb'])